# Related to linear equation with one variable

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

My question is-
Solve completely:
$$ ax + b - \frac{5x + 2ab}{5} = \frac{1}{4}$$

Any guidance to solve this question would be helpful.

Comment: Try isoleting $x$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: you have $$ax + b - x - \frac{2}{5}ab = \frac{1}{4}.$$

- move all the terms that has an $x$ in them to one side and everything to the other side:
  $$ ax - x = \frac{1}{4} + \frac{2}{5}ab - b$$
- Factor out $x$ from each term. (on the left)
- Divide by the "stuff" that is multiplied by $x$

Comment: thanks.Was really helpful.

Comment: No problem. Glad it was helpful.